# VirtualBox on Windows host -- preserve Windows keyboard shortcut while in full screen

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host. In Windows 10 I enjoy using multiple desktops and using the keyboard shortcuts **Ctrl+Windows+(Left || Right) arrows** to switch between desktops.

When I am in full screen mode for my VirtualBox Ubuntu environment, I am unable to use any Windows keys. Is there a configuration in VirtualBox where I can map this particular keystroke back to my host machine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to map the keystroke back to the host machine.

However, what you can do is to press the Host key (right Ctrl key by default) first then use any shortcut available in the host.